# Touch end event on GoogleMap iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to work on Google Map with some UIView. My requirement is : If I touch the MapView, one of UIView will disappear(animated) and it will remain disappear until I release the touch from MapView. I managed to disappear the UIView from screen on touching the MapView using the below code :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt 
coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
self.animate()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView,
idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
self.collapse()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
//
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
```

On dragging map and release { Touch --> Drag --> Lift } I can detect Finger Lift using **idleAt**. But I couldn't detect with anything if I { Touch --> hold --> Lift }. You can consider **Uber or Ola** app MapView for example

Answer (score 8):

You can use GoogleMaps GMSMapViewDelegate:

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

This will call when Google map start moving and idle.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
//
}

// Touch drag and lift
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
//
}

// Touch and lift
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("yes")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have the touchesEnd event to detect when the finger is lifted off the screen, so that I can bring back my UIView.

Comment: "idleAt" will call after the finger is lifted Off from screen. We have developed an app Same like Uber, in this we have use "idleAt" to detect touchesEnd.

Comment: Thanks, idleAt is being called at lifting finger. It is called only when I { Touch --> Drag --> Lift }  ..  not in case of { Touch --> Lift }. 
I need it to be called in both cases.

Comment: @VipiNNegi see my updated answer. "didTapAt" will call at { Touch --> Lift },  "idleAt" will call at  { Touch --> Drag --> Lift }

Comment: Silly of me :( , actually I was looking for { Touch --> hold --> Lift } instead of { Touch --> Lift }, Touch>Lift is just a simple tap.

Comment: you can use "didLongPressAt"

Comment: 'didLongPressAt' will be called at { Touch --> hold } but when I Lift .. nothing is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131905/discussion-between-vipin-negi-and-vinupriya-arivazhagan).